# Heroku free quota per-app or total?

Tags: heroku

Is heroku's free 750 hours separate per app, or is it a total of 750 hours shared across all your apps?

From their site:

> "Each app you create has free access to 750 dyno-hours per month and a starter-tier database."

However, from another answer on StackOverflow:

> "Heroku provides, for free, 1 dyno. A dyno is an instance of your application running and responding to requests. If each instance of your application can serve each request in 100ms, then you get 600 requests/minute with the free account."

Comment: I'd trust the Heroku docs over an answer about Heroku on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of what it says there and my experience it's per app.  That's talking about instances of dynos not apps. "If **each instance of your application** can serve each request in 100ms, then you get 600 requests/minute with the free account."

Comment: State changed from up to down
 Idling because quota is exhausted   Stopping all processes with SIGTERM

Answer (score 1):

Each app you create within Heroku gets 750 dyno-hours per month for free.  The number of requests your app can receive depend on the *configuration of the app*.  For example, an app running `unicorn` can handle more requests than an app running something else, as `unicorn` can run multiple workers per dyno.

I've personally run an app on Heroku with 3 `unicorn` *workers* on *one dyno*, 24 hours a day, all month, and always been free (because that is ~750 dyno-hours).